# Production Application Crashes when accessing X509Certificate2 Key Data

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, security, windows-services

Really hoping you can help me with the following.

I have created an .Net Core Application that is run as a windows service.
I'm trying to open a certificate in order to decrypt the app settings.

The certificate I am using on my local machine and the test server is the same certificate.
The Public key for the certificate in question is an X5092.

I have the following code to read the Certificate from the store to get the values.

```
public void Start()
{
    using (var store = new X509Store(Location))
    {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var signingCert = store.Certificates.Find(CriteriaType, _thumb, false);

        _logger.Warning($"Number of certs found {signingCert.Count}");

        var firstCert = signingCert[0];

        _logger.Warning($"Subject - {firstCert.Subject}");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        try
        {
            _logger.Warning($"Private Key - {firstCert.PrivateKey}");
            _logger.Warning($"Get RSA Private Key Method {firstCert.GetRSAPrivateKey()}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The application finds the certificate using the ThumbPrint enum, the thumbprint and doesn't care if the certificate is valid or not.
The value of firstCert is the cert I am after.
The "Subject" prints to the log file correctly as well as any of the other props apart from the Public and Private Key props.

My application crashes as soon as I call any of the following

```
firstCert.PrivateKey
firstCert.GetRSAPrivateKey()
firstCert.PublicKey.{anotherProp}
```

The crashes happen under the following conditions.

1. The server is rebooting.
2. The application is set to automatic start up.
3. The application is run as a service.
4. The Logon is Local System Account.
   When the application does crash, there are no logs after I try to access key data of the cert.
   No exception caught, the application fails to start, I only find this out by looking at the services to which is says stopped.

The application works correctly in the following conditions

1. When debugging on my local machine.
2. Running as a service, on automatic start, as the Local System Account on my local machine.
3. As above but started from the services feature.
4. On the test server but with a delayed start up.
5. On the test server but started from the services feature.

The app written is .Net5
My local machine is windows 10 enterprise.
The server is 2012 R2.

Comment: I've had a similar issue where the app couldn't start when deployed and there were no useful logs, but it all pointed to the app not being able to access the x509 certificate. I registered the cert by reading it into bytes instead of giving it a path, but it didn't help. It worked when I used a different cert, so I wrote it off as some problem with the cert file. Weird thing is that it worked on my machine :(

Comment: Side note: you might want to check that `signingCert` isn't empty before accessing `signingCert[0]`, otherwise that could lead to an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: thank you @abdusco, i appreciate the help. It can access the cert, I can print all the properties apart from the keys, as soon as  try to access the public or private key its crashes.

Comment: @Métoule this is just a test app. I know for sure it would find the cert. Also, it would throw an exception which would bubble up.

Answer (score 0):

So, we ran into this problem recently, every time rebooted the machine the service (which was set to start automatically) would fail to start with no exceptions or errors (just an error from the service control manager in the event viewer stating the timeout of 30000 ms had been hit). After a lot of debugging we found it was hanging after trying to access the private key from a certificate (which led us to this post).

After more investigation we found that there was a dependent service that wasn't being started in time, this was the CNG Key Isolation service (KeyIso is the service name). We updated our service to be created with a dependency on this and now it starts correctly each time.

For powershell it was a case of adding `-DependsOn "KeyIso"` to the `New-Service` command we had. It can also be added via the `sc` command.